# Как правильно делать запросы в Laravel 5.2 Eloquent

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Не понимаю, как правильно делать запросы в `Eloquent` и как фильтровать в связанных таблицах.

Обо всем по порядку.

Есть три таблицы:

1. Пользователь `users` - стандартная из коробки `Laravel`
2. Группы `groups` - `id`, `title`, `description`
3. связывающая их таблица `pivot_user_group` - `id`, `user_id`, `group_id`, `isModerator`

Модели:

**User**

```
 <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        ...

        public function groups()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Group', 'pivot_user_group')->withPivot(['isModerator']);
        }

        ...
    /*
    * Где-то тут надо использовать эту функцию?
    * public function groupsWhere()
    * {
    *    return $this->groupsWith()
    *        ->wherePivot('isModerator','=', 1);
    * }
    */
    }
```

**Group**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Group extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'pivot_user_group');
    }


}
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Как вытаскивать `-> count()` с `where('isModerator','=',1)`?
2. Как вообще вытаскивать список пользователей подходящих по данному условию?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->relation()->wherePivot('isModerator', true)->whatever...`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: для того что бы вытащить количество строк с isModerate в промежуточной таблице мне нужно в модели `public static function groupscount() 
    {
        $counter = 0;
        $users = self::all();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $counter += $user
                ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Group', 'pivot_user_group')
                ->groupBy('group_id')
                ->wherePivot('isModerate', '=', 1)
                ->count();
        }
    return $counter;
    }` , а в контроллере просто `echo App\User::groupscount();`

Comment: groupsWhere вы написали правильно (только groupsWith() поменяйте на groups()), чтобы посчитать модели по условию используйте `$this->groupsWhere()->count()` или `$this->groups()->wherePivot(..)->count()`, чтобы посчитать строки в pivot таблице, используйте builder `Db::table(..)->where(..)->count()`

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь разобраться.